# Trouble with 2 RewriteRule

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, rewriting

I have a trouble with two Rewriterule in my htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/([0-9]+)/?$ viewauthor.php?lg=$1&cat=$2&nameauthor=$3&id=$4 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/([0-9]+)/?$ viewbook.php?lg=$1&cat=$2&namebook=$3&id=$4 [NC,L]
```

I can't access to the second rewriterule cause it's similar.
to see which page I am on. I put `echo $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];` in those two page.

When I remove  the flag `[NC,L]`, I access to the second rewriterule but the `lg=viewauthor.php` instead `lg=en`.

Comment: They're not similar, they're exactly the same. You can't route to 2 different pages from the same request. You need something else to differentiate them, why not start authors with `/author/` and books with `/book/`?

Comment: Thanks for the response its work when its start by  author or book but. in my script I can't start by author or book  I need to use lg variable first. another idea.

Answer (score 0):

You need a prefix to differentiate but you don't capture it, it's just used to match a rule:

```
RewriteRule ^author/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/([0-9]+)/?$ viewauthor.php?lg=$1&cat=$2&nameauthor=$3&id=$4 [B,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^book/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/([0-9]+)/?$ viewbook.php?lg=$1&cat=$2&namebook=$3&id=$4 [B,NC,L]
```

Now make your URLs like `/author/foo/far/faz/1` and `/book/boo/bar/baz/2`. Note the addition of the `B` flags.

Comment: Thanks to all i resolve my problem with this:                           RewriteRule ^(.*)/author/(.*)/([0-9]+)/?$ viewauthor.php?cat=author&lg=$1&nom=$2&id=$3 
RewriteRule ^(.*)/book/(.*)/([0-9]+)/?$ viewbook.php?lg=$1&cat=book&miw=$2&id=$3                                                                                         Thanks again

Comment: Good, but don't just thank people, That's what upvotes/accepting answers is for.

Comment: Are you positive? Answer is showing 0 up- and 0 downvotes, and is not accepted.

Comment: When i vote i see mesaj i can't see my vote with my reputation

Comment: Ah, sorry. I guess the answer wasn't helpful enough to accept.